# Notepad++: unwanted spacing added when word-wrapping with auto tabbing

Tags: notepad++, spacing

I've just started using Notepad++ and I'm seeing this single-line space pop up whenever a line is wrapped that is indented automatically. Note that this is not an actual line, it's just spacing. There is a demo of this behavior in "demo"

Edit: also note that this only happens when word-wrapping, if I press enter the blank line is not added.

Edit 2: was playing around with it a bit more, and noticed that this only occurs if, when word wrapping, there is are either 0 spaces on the current line or 1 space at the very beginning, there is a demo of this behavior in "demo 2"

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1svSw.gif)

[demo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFPWt.gif)

Final edit: I believe this is an unavoidable 'feature', as I found a discussion (https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/20008/line-wrap-in-the-current-version/9) where this is brought up, and addressed as word-wrapping for a full line being unneeded since it's very unlikely that there'll be a full line with no spaces. The only issue I see with this is that you might have Notepad++ set to a smaller window size and hence word-wrapping happens much earlier.

If anybody knows of a hack or anything to chop up lines regardless of whether or not there's a space, I'd love to hear it, but I can't imagine there is.